# Rewriting the flatten function

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I have written a version of the underscore _.flatten function and it works but I don't understand why the first works but not the second version.

```
var flatten = function (array, result) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var current = array[i];
    if (Array.isArray(current)) {
      result.push.apply(array, flatten(current));
    }
    else {
      result.push(current);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

var nested = [1, [2], [3, [[[4]]]]];
console.log(flatten(nested));
// [1,2,3,4]
```

vs:

```
var flatten = function (array, result) {
  var result = [];
  array.forEach(function (current) {
    if (Array.isArray(current)) {
      result.push.apply(array, flatten(current));
    }
    else {
      result.push(current);
    }
  });
  return result;
};
var nested = [1, [2], [3, [[[4]]]]];
console.log(flatten(nested));
// [1]
```

Comment: what data is being passed to it so we can test?

Comment: it's just at the bottom; the nested array>> 'var nested = [1, [2], [3, [[[4]]]]];'

Comment: Why do your functions have a `result` parameter that is never used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing the wrong first argument to `result.push.apply`:

```
result.push.apply(array, flatten(current));
// ---------------^^^^^
```

You want to call `push` on `result` but you're actually calling `array.push`. You want to say:

```
result.push.apply(result, flatten(current));
```

so that `push` gets `result` as its `this` when it is called.

---

A more interesting question is why your `for`-based implementation "works" even though its implementation is confused. If you throw a

```
console.log(nested);
```

at the bottom of the first one, you'll see that your `for`-based implementation makes a mess of its argument; hence the scare-quotes on "works".

If you mentally step through your `if`:

```
if (Array.isArray(current)) {
  result.push.apply(array, flatten(current));
}
else {
  result.push(current);
}
```

you'll see that it is modifying `array` as you're iterating over it. But everything it adds to `array` is another array while the non-arrays end up in `result` where you want them.

If you start with:

```
var nested = [1, [2], [3, [[[4]]]], 5]
```

you'll see that it doesn't work in another way because you'll end up with:

```
[1, 5, 2, 3, 4]
```

as your final result (and some other mess in `nested`). Your `for`-based implementation only appeared to work because you happened to give it a specially structured input.

Comment: can you explain why it works correctly in the first one?  more confused about why it DID work there than in his not working solution

Comment: @dave I was working on that when your comment came in. The first one doesn't actually work at all. But yeah, that's the more interesting question :)

Comment: Thank you so much, seems so obvious now I can't believe didn't even see that before! @muistooshort

Comment: Took me awhile to spot it too even though I kept looking at that `result.push.apply` call: the hardest problems to spot are the ones right out in the open staring you right in the face.